# Entity Framework Query ideas (group by)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I am drawing a blank on how to do this within Entity Framework query (other than in multiple steps)

Car table:

```
id (identity) | CarName | RegisteredOn | RegisteredBy
```

Basically i need to retrieve a distinct list of cars, each with the latest registered user.

If i have a table of cars, each car will be entered 1 or multiple times on different dates it was registered.

so CarA can be entered 5 times, with 3 owners, CarB can be entered 1 time and so on.

Let's say I want a query for 2/1/2011 to see all the cars in the table with the last registered name.

Is that easily achievable with Linq? would it require 2 queries, first to get list of all cars, 2nd to join in the latest registered user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, something like...

```
var q = from c in Context.Cars
        group c by c.Name into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(gc => gc.RegisteredOn)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```